# ISC DHCPD class is not assigned

Tags: dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I'm trying to setup a boot server which *only* answers to devices which want to boot over the network. Depending on the boot rom, I need to deliver different boot images, the other settings are common.

My current configuration (/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf) is:

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 60;
max-lease-time 100;
log-facility local7;

class "DM814x ROM" {
        match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 10) = "DM814x ROM";
        filename "u-boot-spl-debrick.bin";
}
class "AM335x U-Boot SPL" {
        match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 17) = "AM335x U-Boot SPL";
        filename "u-boot-debrick.img";
}
# more possible strings: "PXEClient", "Etherboot"

log (error,
    concat ("TEST DUMP:"
    , " mac=", binary-to-ascii(16, 8, ":", substring(hardware, 1, 6))
    , " substr='", substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 10), "'"
    , " vendor='", option vendor-class-identifier, "'"
    #, " dhcpvendor='", option dhcp-vendor-identifier, "'"
    )
);

subnet 10.0.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        #server-name "10.0.42.1";
        #option routers 10.0.42.1;
        #option domain-name "example.org";
        #option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;
        pool {
                range 10.0.42.200 10.0.42.240;
                allow members of "DM814x ROM";
                allow members of "AM335x U-Boot SPL";
                #allow dynamic bootp clients;
        }
}
```

Now, it seems that the class is not assigned. I also tried to implement it using subclasses but with the same effect. The log statement showed me that the returned string is correct (and `substring()` really uses base 0 [which is not documented]).

For some tests I used the `allow dynamic bootp clients` statement. The result was that the host received an ip address but without the file name which shows that the class was still not assigned.

Comment: Where's the next-server statement that tells it where to grab the file?

Comment: This will come later (with a bunch of other settings like dns etc.). For first, I want to keep the example as simple as possible. (Some pages also say it's `server-name` not `next-server` which is used as tftp server)

Answer (score 1):

I took what I saw from your config and adapted it to what mine sort of looks like

```
#change next-server to your ip
next-server 10.0.42.1;

ddns-updates off;
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

log-facility local7;

class "DM814X_MACS" {
    match if (binary-to-ascii(16,8,":",substring(hardware, 1, 3)) = "d0:39:72");
}

subnet 10.0.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    pool {
        allow dynamic bootp clients;
        allow members of "DM814X_MACS";
        range dynamic-bootp 10.0.42.200 10.0.42.240;
        if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 10) = "DM814x ROM" {
            filename "u-boot-spl-debrick.bin";
        } elsif substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 17) = "AM335x U-Boot SPL" {
            filename "u-boot-debrick.img";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please go over a bit what changes you made and why?

Comment: @Colyn1377 The line with "d0:39:72" filters the macs down to Texas Instruments devices which will always be used by the bootrom. The allow dynamic bootp clients; is required for the bootp process. The line with "AM335x U-Boot SPL" might need to be moved to its own pool since its possible to u-boot to change the mac at this stage though. Also this allows the proper files to be transfered since its not in the class discovery part